# Automatically create and assign terms based on url

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

How can we automatically create and assign taxonomy terms based on the URL?

For instance: /climate-change/statistics/new-zealand/polar-bear-maulings

Existing terms: climate-change, statistics

How can Drupal assign climate-change, statistics to the node, and also create and assign new-zealand and polar-bear-maulings to it as well?

Comment: are you trying to do this on edit or view of the node?

Comment: Create/edit only

Comment: should be able to do it with Rules and Path Rules then